# How do you print in this circumstance

Tags: python-3.x, printing

```
N=5
for rate in range (5, 15, 5):
    for principal in  range (10000, 15000, 1000):
        simple = principal * (1 + (rate / 100) * N)
        compound = principal * (1 + (rate / 100) ** N
        print (rate, principle, simple, compound)
```

Comment: You forgot to close your parentheses on the line before the `print`, if that's what you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want to print it. But, everything that you want to print is numbers. You could format your print, or you could just print everything as a string:

`print(str(rate)+', '+str(principal)+', '+str(simple)+', '+str(compund))`

But this is the same as printing it as you've tried:

`print(rate, principal, simple, compound)`

```
>>>
5, 10000, 12500.0, 10000.003125000001
5, 11000, 13750.0, 11000.003437500001
5, 12000, 15000.0, 12000.003750000002
5, 13000, 16250.0, 13000.004062500002
5, 14000, 17500.0, 14000.004375000002
10, 10000, 15000.0, 10000.1
10, 11000, 16500.0, 11000.11
10, 12000, 18000.0, 12000.12
10, 13000, 19500.0, 13000.130000000001
10, 14000, 21000.0, 14000.140000000001
```

It's really up to you. There's some mistakes in the pasted code of yours, but I'm assuming you meant the following:

```
N=5

for rate in range(5,15,5):
    for principal in range(10000,15000,1000):
        simple = principal * (1+(rate/100)*N)
        compound = principal * (1+(rate/100)**N)
```